# Guard для подписок GraphQL на NestJS

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs

#### В чём проблема

Вообщем решил настроить `jwt` авторизацию для `GraphQL` на `Nest.js`, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что для подписок (`subscriptions`) guard не работает, поскольку `req` - не определён, оно и понятно, потому что подписки используют `websocket`.

Я изучил следующий [материал](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/394), но так и не смог решить проблему.
Вот мой конфиг `GraphQL` на данный момент:

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  playground: false,
  autoSchemaFile: 'src/graphql/generated/schema.gql',
  subscriptions: {
    'graphql-ws': true,
    'subscriptions-transport-ws': true,
  },
  plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
}),
```

Собрал его из офф. документации `Nest`
Ну а вот и сам `guard`

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql'

@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context)
    return ctx.getContext().req
  }
}
```

Дефолтный, тоже с офф. документации

Проверяю всё в `Apollo Explorer`, там при подписке получаю это

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logIn') # req is undefined

Без `'subscriptions-transport-ws'` `Apollo` отказывается работать, так, что настраивать `guard` нужно под него, но лучше для обоих.

#### Что я пробовал

Может быть для `GraphQL` без `Apollo` это сработало бы, но увы, ошибка та же

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    // chaincode modules
    ParticipantModule,
    PersonModule,
    CauseModule,
    TransactionModule,
    // apolloServer config: use forRootAsync to import AuthModule and inject AuthService
    GraphQLModule.forRootAsync({
      // import AuthModule
      imports: [AuthModule],
      // inject authService
      useFactory: async (authService: AuthService) => ({
        debug: true,
        playground: true,
        installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
        autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gql',
        // pass the original req and res object into the graphql context,
        // get context with decorator `@Context() { req, res, payload, connection }: GqlContext`
        // req, res used in http/query&mutations, connection used in webSockets/subscriptions
        context: ({ req, res, payload, connection }: GqlContext) => ({ req, res, payload, connection }),
        // configure graphql cors here
        cors: {
          origin: e.corsOriginReactFrontend,
          credentials: true,
        },
        // subscriptions/webSockets authentication
        subscriptions: {
          // get headers
          onConnect: (connectionParams: ConnectionParams) => {
            // convert header keys to lowercase
            const connectionParamsLowerKeys = mapKeysToLowerCase(connectionParams);
            // get authToken from authorization header
            const authToken: string = ('authorization' in connectionParamsLowerKeys)
              && connectionParamsLowerKeys.authorization.split(' ')[1];
            if (authToken) {
              // verify authToken/getJwtPayLoad
              const jwtPayload: GqlContextPayload = authService.getJwtPayLoad(authToken);
              // the user/jwtPayload object found will be available as context.currentUser/jwtPayload in your GraphQL resolvers
              return { currentUser: jwtPayload.username, jwtPayload, headers: connectionParamsLowerKeys };
            }
            throw new AuthenticationError('authToken must be provided');
          },
        },
      }),
      // inject: AuthService
      inject: [AuthService],
    }),
  ],
})
```

**guard**

```
@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {

  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    // req used in http queries and mutations, connection is used in websocket subscription connections, check AppModule
    const { req, connection } = ctx.getContext();

    // if subscriptions/webSockets, let it pass headers from connection.context to passport-jwt
    return (connection && connection.context && connection.context.headers)
      ? connection.context
      : req;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я <strike>не</strike>много поэкспериментировал и нашёл идеальное и простое для меня решение. Не знаю, на сколько оно правильное и оптимальное, но в `Apollo Explorer` я без проблем могу использовать заголовок авторизации, что насчёт реального клиента, то я дополню ответ, если что-то изменится.
Я использую `NestJS + Fastify` и `Apollo`, так что вероятно это решение не универсальное.

**GraphQLModule**

```
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloDriver,
  playground: false,
  autoSchemaFile: 'src/graphql/generated/schema.gql',
  subscriptions: {
    'graphql-ws': true,
    'subscriptions-transport-ws': {
      onConnect: params => ({ headers: toLowerKeys(params) /* Authorization -> authorization */ }),
    },
  },
  plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
}),
```

**Guard**

```
@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context)
    const { req, headers } = ctx.getContext()
    return req ?? { headers }
  }
}
```